# justify chapter* for southall

Tags: spacing

I have searched but couldn't find an answer to how to make `\chapter*`-names be left justified for the chapterstyle `southall`. The following MWE illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\chapterstyle{southall}

\begin{document}

\chapter{I am totally justified thanks to the ``1"}
\chapter*{I want to start where the ``1" starts above}
\section{I am also justified}
\section*{I am as well}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: Thank you for the solution, it works wonders in mainmatter (I use this in the memoir setting), but for the words 'Contents' in toc (which has the same format as chapter) and 'Acknowledgements' (which are in frontmatter) there are still problems. Is there a way to fix that as well to make it look consistent? As it is now it seems that the chapters in the frontmatter do not want to behave well, while the one in mainmatter do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the style to take into account the `*`-variant, which makes 
the conditional `\ifm@mpn@new@schap` true.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
%% Thomas Dye's southall chapter style (modified)
\makechapterstyle{southall-mod}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{5\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{36pt}%    \headindent
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{\textwidth}% \rightblock
  \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\beforechapskip}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
%%%  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\rmfamily\raggedright}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\rmfamily\memRTLraggedright}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \ifm@mpn@new@schap\else
      \begin{minipage}[t][\baselineskip][b]{\beforechapskip}
        {\vspace{0pt}\chapnumfont%%%\figureversion{lining}
                     \thechapter}
      \end{minipage}%
    \fi}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \ifm@mpn@new@schap\else
      \hfill
    \fi\begin{minipage}[t]{\midchapskip}
      {\vspace{0pt}\chaptitlefont ##1\par}\end{minipage}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \hrulefill \par\nobreak\noindent \vskip \afterchapskip}}
\makeatother


\chapterstyle{southall-mod}

\begin{document}

\chapter{I am totally justified thanks to the ``1''}
\chapter*{I want to start where the ``1'' starts above}
\section{I am also justified}
\section*{I am as well}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `"` for closing quotes; type in two apostrophes like I did.