# Justify frontmatter for chapter style southall

Tags: spacing, memoir

This question is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278296/justify-chapter-for-southall); I wonder how one could modify the `southall` chapter style so that the word ''Contents'' and ''Acknowledgements'' become justified to the left. The linked answer works for ''Acknowledgements'' if I replace `\chapter{Acknowledgements}` with `\chapter*{Acknowledgements}`, but then I do not know how to add it (in a correct way) to the toc. In either case, ''Contents'' is something I cannot fix unfortunately. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
%% Thomas Dye's southall chapter style (modified)
\makechapterstyle{southall-mod}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{5\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{36pt}%    \headindent
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{\textwidth}% \rightblock
  \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\beforechapskip}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
%%%  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\rmfamily\raggedright}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\rmfamily\memRTLraggedright}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \ifm@mpn@new@schap\else
      \begin{minipage}[t][\baselineskip][b]{\beforechapskip}
        {\vspace{0pt}\chapnumfont%%%\figureversion{lining}
                     \thechapter}
      \end{minipage}%
    \fi}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \ifm@mpn@new@schap\else
      \hfill
    \fi\begin{minipage}[t]{\midchapskip}
      {\vspace{0pt}\chaptitlefont ##1\par}\end{minipage}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \hrulefill \par\nobreak\noindent \vskip \afterchapskip}}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{southall-mod}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\maketitle
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
Thank you! Especially if you can help me justify ``Acknowledgements'' and ``Contents'' to the left.
southall-mod unfortunately does not do this.

\mainmatter
\chapter{I am totally justified thanks to the ``1''}
\chapter*{I am also justified thanks to southall-mod}
\section{I am also justified}
\section*{I am as well}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

The result:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do `\chapterstyle{southall}` in the frontmatter and `\chapterstyle{southall-mod}` when you need it. However, I don't think it's a good idea: *all* chapters should share the style.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't express myself clearly. Yes I want the chapters to share the same style, and as it is now, only chapters in mainmatter get justified (as seen in the pictures). The code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is taken from you @egreg in the linked answer, but doesn't work for the things I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to add another conditional: if we are not in the main matter, `\chapter` should behave like `\chapter*` as far as formatting is concerned.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
%% Thomas Dye's southall chapter style (modified)
\makechapterstyle{southall-mod}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{5\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{36pt}%    \headindent
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{\textwidth}% \rightblock
  \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\beforechapskip}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
%%%  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\rmfamily\raggedright}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\rmfamily\memRTLraggedright}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \ifm@mpn@new@schap\else
      \if@mainmatter
        \begin{minipage}[t][\baselineskip][b]{\beforechapskip}
          {\vspace{0pt}\chapnumfont%%%\figureversion{lining}
                        \thechapter}
        \end{minipage}%
      \fi
    \fi}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \ifm@mpn@new@schap\else
      \if@mainmatter\hfill\fi
    \fi\begin{minipage}[t]{\midchapskip}
      {\vspace{0pt}\chaptitlefont ##1\par}\end{minipage}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \hrulefill \par\nobreak\noindent \vskip \afterchapskip}}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{southall-mod}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\maketitle
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
Thank you! Especially if you can help me justify ``Acknowledgements'' and ``Contents'' to the left.
southall-mod unfortunately does not do this.

\mainmatter
\chapter{I am totally justified thanks to the ``1''}
\chapter*{I am also justified thanks to southall-mod}
\section{I am also justified}
\section*{I am as well}
\end{document}
```

[image]